# Terraform conditional argument block

Tags: azure, conditional-statements, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have created a module in order deploy the below `azurerm_automation_schedule` resource:

```
resource "azurerm_automation_schedule" "example" {
  name                    = var.aaname
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  automation_account_name = azurerm_automation_account.example.name
  frequency               = var.frequency              
  interval                = var.interval
  timezone                = "Australia/Perth"
  start_time              = "2014-04-15T18:00:15+02:00"
  description             = "This is an example schedule"

  monthly_occurrence {
                      day = monthly_occurrence.value.day
                      occurrence = monthly_occurrence.value.occurrence
                  }
 }
```

The existence of **monthly_occurrence** block argument must be conditional as it is **only** needed when the **frequency is "Month"** otherwise it throws error.

Is there a way to create this **monthly_occurrence** block argument conditionally?  I am using terraform 0.13.5 and azurerm 2.38.0

I have tried with **for_each** but i couldn't find the solution.  Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [dynamic block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) to make `monthly_occurrence` conditional. For example:

```
resource "azurerm_automation_schedule" "example" {
  name                    = var.aaname
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  automation_account_name = azurerm_automation_account.example.name
  frequency               = var.frequency              
  interval                = var.interval
  timezone                = "Australia/Perth"
  start_time              = "2014-04-15T18:00:15+02:00"
  description             = "This is an example schedule"

  dynamic "monthly_occurrence" {
    for_each = var.frequency == "Month" ? [1] : []
    content {
       day = monthly_occurrence.value.day
       occurrence = monthly_occurrence.value.occurrence
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by combining the [conditional expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/conditionals.html) with [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) in order to create a [conditional dynamic block](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/expressions?in=terraform/configuration-language&utm_source=WEBSITE&utm_medium=WEB_IO&utm_offer=ARTICLE_PAGE&utm_content=DOCS) for the monthly occurence.

You'll have something like this:

```
  dynamic "monthly_occurrence" {
    for_each = var.frequency == Month ? 1 : 0
    content {
       day = monthly_occurrence.value.day
       occurrence = monthly_occurrence.value.occurrence
    }
  }
```

Comment: for_each needs a list, so most probably you meant `var.frequency == Month ? [1] : [0]`